# Is there term to refer to the desire for a coherent narrative to one's life?

Tags: social-psychology, belief

Looking to see if there is a pre-existing term to describe this type of belief/hope.

By "coherent narrative" I mean a narrative that is alike that of a story, with an overall meaningful arc. This could also be phrased as the desire for one's life to be as fated and complete as that of a scripted character.

This is part of an attempt to write a piece linking media exposure to performative behaviours and to the feelings of purposelessness caused by the lack of such an organised narrative to life.

I have no formal education in psychology and so am just looking for any keywords to find resources to learn more about this phenomenon, and any information that can be shared here! :)